# Adi Shankaracharya's biography

Tags: adi-shankaracharya, book-recommendation

What are good Hindi /English or Telugu translation of Adi Shankaracharya's biography, Shankara Vijayam.

Answer (score 5):

The well accepted and most authentic biography of Adi Shankracharya is "Shankara Digvijaya" by [Vidyaranya Madhavacharya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vidyaranya) who was [12th Jagadguru](https://www.sringeri.net/jagadgurus) of [Sringeri Sharada Peetha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sringeri_Sharada_Peetham).

- Biography of Adi Shankaracharya based on Madhaviya Shankra Digvijaya is available for reading online in five parts from Sringeri Sharada Peetha official website: [**Madhaviya Shankara Digvijayam
  The Biography of Sri Adi Shankaracharya**](https://www.sringeri.net/history/sri-adi-shankaracharya/biography/abridged-madhaviya-shankara-digvijayam)
- Original Sanskrit work is available from Interner Archive: [Shankara Digvijaya by Madhavacharya (Vidyaranya Swami) Satika [*Sanskrit*]](https://archive.org/details/Shankara.Digvijaya.Satika).

**English translation of Shankara Dig Vijaya** is published by Sri RamaKrishna Math Chennai, available in pdf from [estudantedavedanta.net](http://estudantedavedanta.net/Sankara-Digvijaya.pdf):

> [image]