# Story of Adi Shankaracharya as per Siva Rahasyam

Tags: scripture, shiva, adi-shankaracharya, reference-request

What is the life story of Adi Shankara Charya as per **Siva Rahasyam**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adi Shankaracharya's biography](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/35898/adi-shankaracharyas-biography)

Comment: @SwiftPushkar plz read full

Comment: I told story which is mentioned in Shiva rashayam